# Допустимо ли выражение?

Tags: частица-не

Допустимо ли выражение? нИ рыба и нЕ мясо. Союз "и" в этом случае для меня обязателен.

Answer (score 3):

*Ни рыба ни мясо* - устойчивый фразеологизм. Добавить "и" в него нельзя. Лучше уж авторский вариант *не рыба и не мясо*.

Comment: А если в стихотворной форме звучит как: "сей слог нИ рыба и нЕ мясо 
но всякий знает..." Причём "и" будет иметь смысловую роль в последующих строках, то возможно ли нИ и нЕ?

Comment: "нИ и нЕ" - создаёт смысловую неразбериху. "Ни" - усиление отрицания, "не" -  просто отрицание. Лучше выбрать единоообразие и понятный смысл (два отрицания с союзом "и" между ними): не рыба и не мясо.